# How to model multi-level data to interpret features of individuals?

Tags: linear-model, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, independence

I am currently very thorn about how to best proceed on the problem I am working on. The data consists of observations (y) of the effect of As on Bs. In particular, y is a percentage difference so the scale does not depend on A and B. I want to estimate the effect that certain attributes of A, certain attributes of B (and not A-B specifically), and certain attributes of the intervention have on the measured effect y. For example: When A has features x_a, B has features x_b, and the intervention has features x_i, the effect is expected to be z.

The data is organised in the following manner: an A has multiple Bs > A-B pairs have multiple interventions (i) > A-B-i triads have multiple days. The problem is the As have different numbers of Bs, A-B pairs have different numbers of interventions, and A-B-p triads have different number of days (d). Within each segment, there is theoretically likely to be correlation.

The objective of this study is interpretation. At first, I thought about approaching this issue using mixed effects modelling, by grouping on A-B pairs and allowing only random intercepts. But this makes the inclusion of features of A and features of B redundant and coefficient interpretation kinda meaningless, correct? And then a big part of the variation might be sucked to each pair's intercept, which is not relevant for the case of understanding features. Additionally, A-B effects may vary from period to period and A-B-i observations may be correlated to previous days (d). On the other hand, using a simple linear regression would seriously violate the independence variation, which also biases results and interpretation, correct?

What would be the best approach to tackle this and get some intuition of the effects of the features?

I unfortunately have a very short deadline for this so any tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking for the best way to approach my objective of associating A and B features to the level of impact of A on B. In particular, which models allow me to interpret coefficients in an unbiased way. Could you please let me know how I can make it more clear? I cannot provide the real data or case but I can make up an example, though I think I described it in the post.